# angular2 http.get returns an error 404?

Tags: angular

[local server api: http://localhost:8000/heroes.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMr1x.jpg)

angular ts code

```
 this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/heroes.json')
.map(res => res.text())
.subscribe(
data => this.randomQuote = data,
err => this.logError(err),
() => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
);
```

but got an error:

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAdCU.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put loca**t**host in the url, not loca**l**host.

As a tip for this kind of issue, if you confirm the URL works in the browser, copy and paste it into the code to ensure that what you're using is the same as what you've confirmed as working.